# YouTube Data API v3 queries per day quota went to 0

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Today our YouTube Data API v3 daily quota went from 37 millions to 0 for no apparent reason. So now we get 403 error when trying to access YouTube API:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
        "domain": "youtube.quota",
        "reason": "quotaExceeded"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In the GCP Queries per day limit appears no be non-editable.

We have checked emails related to the API client but there seems to be no warnings or notifications about anything related to the issue.

Any idea on why this could happen?

Comment: It happens apply for a new extension.

Comment: They can be rather heavy handed with these quota audits.